# Adding a link into wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

i have a shortcode that posts recent blog entries from a certain category on one of my web pages, however i want to display a static link at the end of everypost, is there anyway to do this?

the following code is used to display the posts:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[display-posts category="competitions" posts_per_page="4" include_excerpt="true" image_size="thumbnail" wrapper="ul"]');
```

Thanks in advance.

```
 <?php


// Create the shortcode
add_shortcode( 'display-posts', 'be_display_posts_shortcode' );
function be_display_posts_shortcode( $atts ) {

    // Original Attributes, for filters
    $original_atts = $atts;

    // Pull in shortcode attributes and set defaults
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'title'              => '',
        'author'              => '',
        'category'            => '',
        'date_format'         => '(n/j/Y)',
        'display_posts_off'   => false,
        'exclude_current'     => false,
        'id'                  => false,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => false,
        'image_size'          => false,
        'include_title'       => true,
        'include_author'      => false,
        'include_content'     => false,
        'include_date'        => false,
        'include_excerpt'     => false,
        'meta_key'            => '',
        'meta_value'          => '',
        'no_posts_message'    => '',
        'offset'              => 0,
        'order'               => 'DESC',
        'orderby'             => 'date',
        'post_parent'         => false,
        'post_status'         => 'publish',
        'post_type'           => 'post',
        'posts_per_page'      => '10',
        'tag'                 => '',
        'tax_operator'        => 'IN',
        'tax_term'            => false,
        'taxonomy'            => false,
        'wrapper'             => 'ul',
        'wrapper_class'       => 'display-posts-listing',
        'wrapper_id'          => false,
    ), $atts, 'display-posts' );

    // End early if shortcode should be turned off
    if( $atts['display_posts_off'] )
        return;

    $shortcode_title = sanitize_text_field( $atts['title'] );
    $author = sanitize_text_field( $atts['author'] );
    $category = sanitize_text_field( $atts['category'] );
    $date_format = sanitize_text_field( $atts['date_format'] );
    $exclude_current = be_display_posts_bool( $atts['exclude_current'] );
    $id = $atts['id']; // Sanitized later as an array of integers
    $ignore_sticky_posts = be_display_posts_bool( $atts['ignore_sticky_posts'] );
    $image_size = sanitize_key( $atts['image_size'] );
    $include_title = be_display_posts_bool( $atts['include_title'] );
    $include_author = be_display_posts_bool( $atts['include_author'] );
    $include_content = be_display_posts_bool( $atts['include_content'] );
    $include_date = be_display_posts_bool( $atts['include_date'] );
    $include_excerpt = be_display_posts_bool( $atts['include_excerpt'] );
    $meta_key = sanitize_text_field( $atts['meta_key'] );
    $meta_value = sanitize_text_field( $atts['meta_value'] );
    $no_posts_message = sanitize_text_field( $atts['no_posts_message'] );
    $offset = intval( $atts['offset'] );
    $order = sanitize_key( $atts['order'] );
    $orderby = sanitize_key( $atts['orderby'] );
    $post_parent = $atts['post_parent']; // Validated later, after check for 'current'
    $post_status = $atts['post_status']; // Validated later as one of a few values
    $post_type = sanitize_text_field( $atts['post_type'] );
    $posts_per_page = intval( $atts['posts_per_page'] );
    $tag = sanitize_text_field( $atts['tag'] );
    $tax_operator = $atts['tax_operator']; // Validated later as one of a few values
    $tax_term = sanitize_text_field( $atts['tax_term'] );
    $taxonomy = sanitize_key( $atts['taxonomy'] );
    $wrapper = sanitize_text_field( $atts['wrapper'] );
    $wrapper_class = sanitize_html_class( $atts['wrapper_class'] );
    if( !empty( $wrapper_class ) )
        $wrapper_class = ' class="' . $wrapper_class . '"';
    $wrapper_id = sanitize_html_class( $atts['wrapper_id'] );
    if( !empty( $wrapper_id ) )
        $wrapper_id = ' id="' . $wrapper_id . '"';


    // Set up initial query for post
    $args = array(
        'category_name'       => $category,
        'order'               => $order,
        'orderby'             => $orderby,
        'post_type'           => explode( ',', $post_type ),
        'posts_per_page'      => $posts_per_page,
        'tag'                 => $tag,
    );

    // Ignore Sticky Posts
    if( $ignore_sticky_posts )
        $args['ignore_sticky_posts'] = true;

    // Meta key (for ordering)
    if( !empty( $meta_key ) )
        $args['meta_key'] = $meta_key;

    // Meta value (for simple meta queries)
    if( !empty( $meta_value ) )
        $args['meta_value'] = $meta_value;

    // If Post IDs
    if( $id ) {
        $posts_in = array_map( 'intval', explode( ',', $id ) );
        $args['post__in'] = $posts_in;
    }

    // If Exclude Current
    if( $exclude_current )
        $args['post__not_in'] = array( get_the_ID() );

    // Post Author
    if( !empty( $author ) )
        $args['author_name'] = $author;

    // Offset
    if( !empty( $offset ) )
        $args['offset'] = $offset;

    // Post Status  
    $post_status = explode( ', ', $post_status );       
    $validated = array();
    $available = array( 'publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'auto-draft', 'future', 'private', 'inherit', 'trash', 'any' );
    foreach ( $post_status as $unvalidated )
        if ( in_array( $unvalidated, $available ) )
            $validated[] = $unvalidated;
    if( !empty( $validated ) )      
        $args['post_status'] = $validated;


    // If taxonomy attributes, create a taxonomy query
    if ( !empty( $taxonomy ) && !empty( $tax_term ) ) {

        // Term string to array
        $tax_term = explode( ', ', $tax_term );

        // Validate operator
        if( !in_array( $tax_operator, array( 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND' ) ) )
            $tax_operator = 'IN';

        $tax_args = array(
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $tax_term,
                    'operator' => $tax_operator
                )
            )
        );

        // Check for multiple taxonomy queries
        $count = 2;
        $more_tax_queries = false;
        while( 
            isset( $original_atts['taxonomy_' . $count] ) && !empty( $original_atts['taxonomy_' . $count] ) && 
            isset( $original_atts['tax_' . $count . '_term'] ) && !empty( $original_atts['tax_' . $count . '_term'] ) 
        ):

            // Sanitize values
            $more_tax_queries = true;
            $taxonomy = sanitize_key( $original_atts['taxonomy_' . $count] );
            $terms = explode( ', ', sanitize_text_field( $original_atts['tax_' . $count . '_term'] ) );
            $tax_operator = isset( $original_atts['tax_' . $count . '_operator'] ) ? $original_atts['tax_' . $count . '_operator'] : 'IN';
            $tax_operator = in_array( $tax_operator, array( 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND' ) ) ? $tax_operator : 'IN';

            $tax_args['tax_query'][] = array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $terms,
                'operator' => $tax_operator
            );

            $count++;

        endwhile;

        if( $more_tax_queries ):
            $tax_relation = 'AND';
            if( isset( $original_atts['tax_relation'] ) && in_array( $original_atts['tax_relation'], array( 'AND', 'OR' ) ) )
                $tax_relation = $original_atts['tax_relation'];
            $args['tax_query']['relation'] = $tax_relation;
        endif;

        $args = array_merge( $args, $tax_args );
    }

    // If post parent attribute, set up parent
    if( $post_parent ) {
        if( 'current' == $post_parent ) {
            global $post;
            $post_parent = get_the_ID();
        }
        $args['post_parent'] = intval( $post_parent );
    }

    // Set up html elements used to wrap the posts. 
    // Default is ul/li, but can also be ol/li and div/div
    $wrapper_options = array( 'ul', 'ol', 'div' );
    if( ! in_array( $wrapper, $wrapper_options ) )
        $wrapper = 'ul';
    $inner_wrapper = 'div' == $wrapper ? 'div' : 'li';


    $listing = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'display_posts_shortcode_args', $args, $original_atts ) );
    if ( ! $listing->have_posts() )
        return apply_filters( 'display_posts_shortcode_no_results', wpautop( $no_posts_message ) );

    $inner = '';
    while ( $listing->have_posts() ): $listing->the_post(); global $post;

        $image = $date = $author = $excerpt = $content = '';

        if ( $include_title )
            $title = '<a class="title" href="' . apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink() ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';

        if ( $image_size && has_post_thumbnail() )  
            $image = '<a class="image" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), $image_size ) . '</a> ';

        if ( $include_date ) 
            $date = ' <span class="date">' . get_the_date( $date_format ) . '</span>';

        if( $include_author )
            $author = apply_filters( 'display_posts_shortcode_author', ' <span class="author">by ' . get_the_author() . '</span>' );

        if ( $include_excerpt ) 
            $excerpt = ' <span class="excerpt-dash">-</span> <span class="excerpt">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</span>';

        if( $include_content ) {
            add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_display-posts', 'be_display_posts_off', 10, 3 );
            $content = '<div class="content">' . apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() ) . '</div>'; 
            remove_filter( 'shortcode_atts_display-posts', 'be_display_posts_off', 10, 3 );
        }

        $class = array( 'listing-item' );
        $class = sanitize_html_class( apply_filters( 'display_posts_shortcode_post_class', $class, $post, $listing, $original_atts ) );
        $output = '<' . $inner_wrapper . ' class="' . implode( ' ', $class ) . '">' . $image . $title . $date . $author . $excerpt . $content . '</' . $inner_wrapper . '>';

        // If post is set to private, only show to logged in users
        if( 'private' == get_post_status( get_the_ID() ) && !current_user_can( 'read_private_posts' ) )
            $output = '';

        $inner .= apply_filters( 'display_posts_shortcode_output', $output, $original_atts, $image, $title, $date, $excerpt, $inner_wrapper, $content, $class );

    endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();

    $open = apply_filters( 'display_posts_shortcode_wrapper_open', '<' . $wrapper . $wrapper_class . $wrapper_id . '>', $original_atts );
    $close = apply_filters( 'display_posts_shortcode_wrapper_close', '</' . $wrapper . '>', $original_atts );

    $return = $open;

    if( $shortcode_title ) {

        $title_tag = apply_filters( 'display_posts_shortcode_title_tag', 'h2', $original_atts );

        $return .= '<' . $title_tag . ' class="display-posts-title">' . $shortcode_title . '</' . $title_tag . '>' . "\n";
    }

    $return .= $inner . $close;

    return $return;
}

/**
 * Turn off display posts shortcode 
 * If display full post content, any uses of [display-posts] are disabled
 *
 * @param array $out, returned shortcode values 
 * @param array $pairs, list of supported attributes and their defaults 
 * @param array $atts, original shortcode attributes 
 * @return array $out
 */
function be_display_posts_off( $out, $pairs, $atts ) {
    $out['display_posts_off'] = true;
    return $out;
}

/**
 * Convert string to boolean
 * because (bool) "false" == true
 *
 */
function be_display_posts_bool( $value ) {
    return !empty( $value ) && 'true' == $value ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Edit that shortcode's PHP code to append the URL!

Comment: So, you want to add a static link to each entry of the result of the shortcode? Can you show us the code for this shortcode?

Comment: How do i do this Akhilesh?

Comment: You need to show us the code for that shortcode. Then only we could suggest where to do the changes.

Comment: edit the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to edit you `$output` variable which is on line 243 on the code you've given above.

A simple amendment to add a static url will do fine, something like this:

```
$static_link = 'http://www.test.com/test';
$output = '<' . $inner_wrapper . ' class="' . implode( ' ', $class ) . '">' . $image . $title . $date . $author . $excerpt . $content . '<a href="'.$static_link.'">Read more</a>' . '</' . $inner_wrapper . '>';
```

Amend this to your requirements, say adding a proper link from the database.

Hope this helps.